# What is $\mathrm{dim}(\mathrm{Sym}(\mathrm{Herm}(H)^{\otimes N})$?

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces, mathematical-physics, tensor-products

The totally symmetric subspace of $(H^k)^{\otimes N}$, with  $H^K$ a $k$-dimensional Hilbert space, has dimension $\binom{N+k-1}{k-1}$. But I now want to know the dimension of the totally symmetric subspace of the $N$-fold tensor product of Hermitian operators on $H^k$, i.e. $\mathrm{dim}(\mathrm{Sym}(\mathrm{Herm}(H^k)^{\otimes N}))$. Is this dimension equal to the dimension of the totally symmetric subspace of density operators on $(H^k)^{\otimes N}$, and if not, is there an explicit expression for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, you mean for $H$ to be a vector space over $\Bbb C$.
Note that $\operatorname{Herm}(H^k)$ is a vector space over $\Bbb R$ (as opposed to $\Bbb C$), and that
$\dim \operatorname{Herm}(H^k) = k^2$. From there, we can simply apply your earlier reasoning to find that 
$$
\mathrm{dim}(\mathrm{Sym}(\mathrm{Herm}(H^k)^{\otimes N})) = \binom{N + k^2 - 1}{k^2 - 1}
$$
Noting that this too is a vector space over $\Bbb R$.

---

If $H$ is a vector space over $\Bbb R$, then $\operatorname{Herm}(H^k)$ is a vector space over $\Bbb R$ with dimension $\frac 12 k(k+1)$.

Comment: You'll have to clarify what you mean by density operators.  If you mean "density operator" in the QM sense of "PSD operator with trace $1$", then you should note that these do **not** form a subspace.

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer. I do mean density operators in the QM sense. If they do not form a (sub)space, then does the question of dimensionality even make sense? The density operators are a subset of the Hermitian operators, so is it correct to say that the dimension of the density operators is equal to (or perhaps smaller than) the Hermitian operators?

It seems you have a small typo in your answer by the way, it should be $\binom{N+k^2-1}{k^2-1}$, right?

Comment: You could talk about the dimension of the span of these operators (as a real vector space), which gives us the same answer, since the span of these operators is the set of Hermitian operators.

Comment: Thanks for the correction; yes, that was a typo.

Comment: Alternatively, you could try to talk about the dimension of the space of density operators as a manifold.  This gives you the answer 
$$
\binom{N + k^2 - 1}{k^2 - 1} -1
$$

Comment: The $-1$ term is because of the constraint on the trace being unity, correct? Would it be possible to reduce the dimension even further by somehow incorporating the constraint on the operators being positive-definite?

Comment: That's correct about the $-1$ term.  We can't reduce the dimension further.  The fact that the matrices are positive definite forces us to look at the space as a real subspace/manifold as opposed to a complex one.

Comment: Try looking at the $2 \times 2$s, for example.  We can write arbitrary PSD matrices as 
$$
\pmatrix{s & u + vi\\u - vi & t}
$$
subject to $s\geq 0,t \geq 0$ and $st \geq u^2 + v^2$.  Forcing the trace to be $1$ amounts to adding the constraint $s = 1-t$.